# R: Ordering data in a cell of data frame

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

I have huge data frame of multiple columns, one of the column contain data like that

```
       No  

   "48.8.1.1." 
   "48.8.1.2."
   "48.8.2." 
   "48.9." 
   "48.10." 
   "48.11." 
   "48.11.1." 
   "48.11.1.1." 
   "48.11.1.2." 
   "48.11.1.2.2.2.2.1."
```

there is no fixed sequence in sub ordering of data.

**PROBLEM :**

instead of

```
   "48.11.1.2.1."
```

some value are not in correct order like ex:

```
   "48.11.1.2.2.2.2.1"
```

no of 2 is extra.
How to remove extra numbers of 2.

I did try some method like resetting index, etc didn't work.
please need some suggestion.

Comment: You provide the problem but provide data that doesn't have the problem.Please edit your question to make it easier to understand.

Comment: @NelsonGon : hey i have edited the question.

Comment: Please include what you have attempted so far

Comment: I see that you have provided a sample of the input data. Please also add (1) Your desired result, and (2) the code that you have tried so far to convert the input into the result.

Comment: The logic isn't clear. If you had to do this manually how do you know which are junk values and which are not?

Comment: @RonakShah : multiple times  same no is reapeating in a string.

Comment: then why is `48.11.1.1` and `48.8.1.1.` not junk?

Comment: they are in series, 48.8,48.9,48.10 after that 48.11 and so on

Comment: @Zeeshan it's unclear what you want. Please add sample(real usable) data using `dput`. Also check my edit to see if it helps. Is it always extra 2s? Some other numbers?

Comment: ok i will do that

Comment: question is updated guys.

Comment: Did you try my answer? Also editing with changes that change the original question will mislead future viewers. The original question focused on 2s and this is similar but different. The edited question is also hard to use as the data and expected output are completely different. Please take time to properly formulate a question before posting.

Comment: @NelsonGon thanks for your feedback. Your previous answer is applicable to only when there is 2 but my serial no column contain data like that also.

Comment: Your original question and data focused on 2s. Better to ask a new question with new data not editing to something completely different.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the whole question also depends on the sequence. To me, it looks like a numbering scheme of sections in an outline.

Comment: @Uwe , Yes this column is in sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

**EDIT::**

```
df$No<-stringr::str_remove_all(df$No,"2.{1,}(?=2.{3,})")
```

Result:

```
             No
1     48.8.1.1.
2     48.8.1.2.
3       48.8.2.
4         48.9.
5        48.10.
6        48.11.
7      48.11.1.
8    48.11.1.1.
9    48.11.1.2.
10 48.11.1.2.1.
```

**ORIGINAL::**

```
df$No<-substring(df$No,1,9)
```

This assumes that the longest string is 9 characters. Everything else is deleted.
Result:

```
df

              No
    1  48.8.1.1.
    2  48.8.1.2.
    3    48.8.2.
    4      48.9.
    5     48.10.
    6     48.11.
    7   48.11.1.
    8  48.11.1.1
    9  48.11.1.2
    10 48.11.1.2
```

Data:

```
df<-read.table(text='No  

               "48.8.1.1." 
               "48.8.1.2."
               "48.8.2." 
               "48.9." 
               "48.10." 
               "48.11." 
               "48.11.1." 
               "48.11.1.1." 
               "48.11.1.2." 
               "48.11.1.2.2.2.2.1." ',header=T,stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Comment: It will work only if string is 9 character but my string has not fixed length.

Comment: Try the edit. Also better to represent exactly what your data looks like. Use `dput` to add sample data.

Answer (score 1):

Under assumption the sequence of character strings represent the numbering of sections in an outline, here is a possible solution:

```
library(data.table)
# reshape to long format
long <- DT[, rn := .I][
  , strsplit(No, "[.]"), by = rn][
    , V1 := as.integer(V1)][
      , lvl := rowid(rn)][]

# find contiguous streaks of rows where there is a gap in levels
nlvl <- long[, .N, keyby = rn][
  , gap := cumsum(c(diff(N), 0L) > 1L)][
    , M := first(N) + 1L, by = gap]

# non-equi anti-join and recast
long[!nlvl[N > M], on = .(rn, lvl >= M, lvl < N)][
  , .(No = paste(V1, collapse = ".")), by = rn]
```

> ```
>     rn          No
>  1:  1    48.8.1.1
>  2:  2    48.8.1.2
>  3:  3      48.8.2
>  4:  4        48.9
>  5:  5       48.10
>  6:  6       48.11
>  7:  7     48.11.1
>  8:  8   48.11.1.1
>  9:  9   48.11.1.2
> 10: 10 48.11.1.2.1
> 11: 11 48.11.1.2.2
> 12: 12 48.11.1.2.3
> 13: 13     48.11.2
> 14: 14   48.11.2.1
> 15: 15 48.11.2.1.1
> 16: 16     48.11.3
> 17: 17   48.11.3.1
> 18: 18          50
> ```

#### Explanation

If I understand correctly, the sequence of character strings represent the numbering of sections in an outline which has been distorted by inserting spurious additional levels. The OP is looking for a method to remove these additional levels.

So, let's assume some rules for numbering the sections of an outline:

1. Gap in section numbers: On the same level, the section numbers are always advanced by 1.
   E.g.,  section `4.1.3` either is followed

   - by `4.1.4` (advance on section level 3)
   - or by `4.2` (if the parent level is advanced)
   - or by `5` (advance to next chapter).
2. Gap in levels: A child level is always 1 level below the parents level. Section numbering on child level starts at 1.
   E.g., section `4.1.3` can be followed by `4.1.3.1` as subsection but *not* by 
   `4.1.3.1.1` which jumps from section level 3 to sub-sub-section level 5.

As OPs question might be related to situation 2, we need to identify rows with a 
gap in levels with respect to the preceeding rows. As a fix all intermediate surplus levels will be removed. The last level is kept as it is presumably numbered correctly.

The first step consists of adding row numbers, splitting the character strings at the `"."`, coercing the section numbrs to integer, and numbering the levels for each row. Now, the section numbers are in long format:

```
 long
```

> ```
>     rn V1 lvl
>  1:  1 48   1
>  2:  1  8   2
>  3:  1  1   3
>  4:  1  1   4
>  5:  2 48   1
>  6:  2  8   2
> [...]
> 25:  9 48   1
> 26:  9 11   2
> 27:  9  1   3
> 28:  9  2   4
> 29: 10 48   1
> 30: 10 11   2
> 31: 10  1   3
> 32: 10  2   4
> 33: 10  2   5
> 34: 10  2   6
> 35: 10  2   7
> 36: 10  1   8
> 37: 11 48   1
> 38: 11 11   2
> 39: 11  1   3
> 40: 11  2   4
> 41: 11  2   5
> 42: 11  2   6
> 43: 11  2   7
> 44: 11  2   8
> 45: 12 48   1
> 46: 12 11   2
> 47: 12  1   3
> 48: 12  2   4
> 49: 12  2   5
> 50: 12  3   6
> 51: 13 48   1
> 52: 13 11   2
> 53: 13  2   3
> 54: 14 48   1
> 55: 14 11   2
> 56: 14  2   3
> 57: 14  1   4
> 58: 15 48   1
> 59: 15 11   2
> 60: 15  2   3
> 61: 15  1   4
> 62: 15  1   5
> 63: 16 48   1
> 64: 16 11   2
> 65: 16  3   3
> 66: 17 48   1
> 67: 17 11   2
> 68: 17  3   3
> 69: 17  3   4
> 70: 17  3   5
> 71: 17  1   6
> 72: 18 50   1
>     rn V1 lvl
> ```

In the next step, contiguous streaks of rows are identified which appear after a gap in the section level. The section level is the number `N` of elements belonging to a row. `gap` marks all rows which come after an illegal jump in the section level. `M` denotes the maximum section level which would be legal according to rule 2 above.

```
nlvl
```

> ```
>     rn N gap M
>  1:  1 4   0 5
>  2:  2 4   0 5
>  3:  3 3   0 5
>  4:  4 2   0 5
>  5:  5 2   0 5
>  6:  6 2   0 5
>  7:  7 3   0 5
>  8:  8 4   0 5
>  9:  9 4   1 5
> 10: 10 8   1 5
> 11: 11 8   1 5
> 12: 12 6   1 5
> 13: 13 3   1 5
> 14: 14 4   1 5
> 15: 15 5   1 5
> 16: 16 3   2 4
> 17: 17 6   2 4
> 18: 18 1   2 4
> ```

In the final step, the additional spurious levels are being eliminated from `long` through a *non-equi anti-join*. Then, the section numbers are recreated by pasting the pieces together.

For comparison, we can join the result with the original data:

```
long[!nlvl[N > M], on = .(rn, lvl >= M, lvl < N)][
  , .(No = paste(V1, collapse = ".")), by = rn][DT, on = "rn"]
```

> ```
>     rn          No               i.No
>  1:  1    48.8.1.1          48.8.1.1.
>  2:  2    48.8.1.2          48.8.1.2.
>  3:  3      48.8.2            48.8.2.
>  4:  4        48.9              48.9.
>  5:  5       48.10             48.10.
>  6:  6       48.11             48.11.
>  7:  7     48.11.1           48.11.1.
>  8:  8   48.11.1.1         48.11.1.1.
>  9:  9   48.11.1.2         48.11.1.2.
> 10: 10 48.11.1.2.1 48.11.1.2.2.2.2.1.
> 11: 11 48.11.1.2.2 48.11.1.2.2.2.2.2.
> 12: 12 48.11.1.2.3     48.11.1.2.2.3.
> 13: 13     48.11.2           48.11.2.
> 14: 14   48.11.2.1         48.11.2.1.
> 15: 15 48.11.2.1.1       48.11.2.1.1.
> 16: 16     48.11.3           48.11.3.
> 17: 17   48.11.3.1     48.11.3.3.3.1.
> 18: 18          50                50.
> ```

#### Data

Extended version of data posted by the OP.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(No = c(
  "48.8.1.1.", 
  "48.8.1.2.",
  "48.8.2." ,
  "48.9." ,
  "48.10." ,
  "48.11." ,
  "48.11.1." ,
  "48.11.1.1." ,
  "48.11.1.2." ,
  "48.11.1.2.2.2.2.1.",
  "48.11.1.2.2.2.2.2.",
  "48.11.1.2.2.3.",
  "48.11.2.",
  "48.11.2.1.",
  "48.11.2.1.1.",
  "48.11.3.",
  "48.11.3.3.3.1.",
  "50."
))
```

Comment: Excellent. I was concerned after I had noticed your intermediate comments and edits of your question that the number of test cases would have been too small to test the rather complex logic thoroughly enough.

Comment: Yah, i did some changes in code, now it is working fine.

Comment: What did you change in the code? Please, let me know how I can improve my answer - Thank you.